# problems with get files in flask

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I'm new to flask and i'm working on uploading files
I have my db local and I can upload files or download them also delete anyone, but I get an error when it comes to get function.

[image]
I get this error in my CLI
return {f'Files':list(x.json() for x in files)}
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ident'

***This is my app.py file :***

```
from io import BytesIO
from flask import Flask , render_template, request , send_file
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse 
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app= Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI']='sqlite:///data.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONs'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)



class Upload(db.Model):
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(50))
    data = db.Column(db.LargeBinary)

@app.route('/' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file= request.files['file']
        upload = Upload(filename=file.filename, data=file.read()) 
        db.session.add(upload)
        db.session.commit()
        return f'Uploaded: {file.filename}' 
    return render_template('index.html')
***//GET FUNCTION***
@app.route('/files', methods=['GET'])
def getFiles():
    files = Upload.query.all()
    return {f'Files':list(x.json() for x in files)}

@app.route('/download/<upload_id>')
def download(upload_id):
    upload = Upload.query.filter_by(id=upload_id).first()
    return send_file(BytesIO(upload.data), attachment_filename=upload.filename , as_attachment=True)

@app.route('/delete/<upload_id>')
def delete(upload_id):
    f = Upload.query.filter_by(id=upload_id).first()
    if f: 
        db.session.delete(f)
        db.session.commit()
        return {'message':'Deleted'}
    else:
        return {'message':'File not found'},404
```

and this is my index it's just a simple HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .center {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask File Uploads Tutorial</h1>
    <div class="center">
        <form method="POST" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <button> Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you try {f'Files':list(x for x in files)} without the json()

Comment: I get this error //
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type Upload is not JSON serializable

Comment: How about {f'Files':list(x.serialize for x in files)} ? Then I am done and I don't know :-)

Comment: I get this one :( //return {f'Files':list(x.serialize for x in files)}
AttributeError: 'Upload' object has no attribute 'serialize' //

Comment: Can you wrap your dictionary with `return jsonify({f'Files':list(x.serialize for x in files)})`. Don't forget to add this import`from flask import jsonify`.

Comment: same thing, i got this err // return jsonify({f'Files':list(x.serialize for x in files)})
AttributeError: 'Upload' object has no attribute 'serialize //

Comment: What is your desired output? Do you want to get the names of the files? Or the data?

Comment: i want to show the data,  
for the name of the files i had a file in my template and I got the names

Comment: I need the data in JSON format so I can call the method in my frontend but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

The `x` value that you are using has no attribute called `json` hence the error.
You can use comprehension to make this work.

```
from flask import jsonify


@app.route('/files', methods=['GET'])
def getFiles():
    files = Upload.query.all()
    return jsonify({'Files': list(dict(id=x.id, 
                                  data=str(x.data),
                                  filename=x.filename ) 
                                  for x in files )})
```

This will return response as list of dictionaries:

```
{ 
  "Files":[
    {
    "id":1,
    "filename": "<filename1>",
    "data":"<file1data>"
     },
    {
     "id":2,
     "filename": "<filename2>",
     "data":"<file2data>"
    }
  .
  .
  .
  ]
}
```